# How to query mongo db by _id?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, database

I am using MongoDB with Spring. I want to query the database by _id.

Currently I have this query:

```
Query q = new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(someId).and("deleted").is(false));
```

But this is giving me StackOverflowError somehow. What's wrong with this query? Or what is a better way of doing this?

Comment: what library are you using?

Comment: also there's a missing )

Comment: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;

version 1.8.1.RELEASE

Comment: missing ) was a typo, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an explicit AND query instead of a chained one using the **`$and`** operator `Criteria.andOperator()` for all of the provided criteria as follows:

```
Query q = new Query(
    new Criteria().andOperator(
        Criteria.where("_id").is(someId),
        Criteria.where("deleted").is("false")
    )
);
```

This is normally used in instances where you can't use `Criteria.and()` to add multiple criteria into the same field, for example

```
Query q = new Query();
q.addCriteria(Criteria.where("age").lt(40).and("age").gt(10));
```

will throw an error, so a workaround would be to use `Criteria.andOperator()` as

```
Query q = new Query();
q.addCriteria(
    Criteria.where("age").exists(true).andOperator(
        Criteria.where("age").gt(10),
        Criteria.where("age").lt(40)
    )
);
```